# GraphJSON serialization in Gremlin.Net

Tags: serialization, gremlin, tinkerpop

I'm trying to query the TinkerPop server (hosted inside docker container) via [CosmosDB client library](https://github.com/evo-terren/Gremlin.Net.CosmosDb), which uses under the hood Gremlin.Net. So I managed to connect it and insert the data, here's intercepted WebSocket request:

```
!application/vnd.gremlin-v1.0+json{
    "requestId": "b64bd2eb-46c3-4095-9eef-768bca2a14ed",
    "op": "eval",
    "processor": "",
    "args": {
        "gremlin": "g.addV(\"User\").property(\"UserId\",2).property(\"CustomerId\",1)"
    }
}
```

The response:

```
{
    "requestId": "b64bd2eb-46c3-4095-9eef-768bca2a14ed",
    "status": {
        "message": "",
        "code": 200,
        "attributes": {
            "host": "/172.19.0.1:38848"
        }
    },
    "result": {
        "data": [
            {
                "id": 0,
                "label": "User",
                "type": "vertex",
                "properties": {}
            }
        ],
        "meta": {}
    }
 }
```

Problem is that I see those properties when I'm connected via gremlin console

```
gremlin> g.V().hasLabel("User").has("CustomerId",1).has("UserId",2).limit(1).valueMap()
==>{UserId=[2], CustomerId=[1]}
```

Also, I'm able to query the TinkerPop server with Gremlin.Net:

```
!application/vnd.gremlin-v1.0+json{
    "requestId": "de35909f-4bc1-4aae-aa5f-28361b3c0933",
    "op": "eval",
    "processor": "",
    "args": {
        "gremlin": "g.V().hasLabel(\"User\").has(\"CustomerId\",1).has(\"UserId\",2).limit(1)"
    }
}
```

But it returns a payload with zero-valued ID and without any properties included:

```
 {
        "requestId": "de35909f-4bc1-4aae-aa5f-28361b3c0933",
        "status": {
            "message": "",
            "code": 200,
            "attributes": {
                "host": "/172.19.0.1:38858"
            }
        },
        "result": {
            "data": [
                {
                    "id": 0,


             "label": "User",
                "type": "vertex",
                "properties": {}
            }
        ],
        "meta": {}
    }
}
```

Tried to swap between GraphSON v1, v2, v3 with no luck. Documentation says that script serializers should include all the properties. Do I have to tweak the config somehow to make this work and return properties?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So it seems that with a version of [3.4](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TINKERPOP-2121?jql=project%20%3D%20TINKERPOP%20AND%20fixVersion%20%3D%203.4.0) of the Gremlin server [ReferenceElementStrategy](https://github.com/apache/tinkerpop/pull/1010/commits/06498eaa418e8cd1779cc421ad30f2f33899f2b3)
was added by default to traversals, to preserve compatibility between binary and script serializers. In our case we wanted to mimic the behavior of the CosmosDB, so to adjust and receive desired behavior just remove the strategy from init script (in our case it was `empty-sample.groovy`

```
globals << [g : graph.traversal().withStrategies(ReferenceElementStrategy.instance())]
```

to

```
globals << [g : graph.traversal()]
```